# Evaluate expression for specific requirement in java

Tags: java, expression, expression-evaluation

I have **Expression** object which has the following:

1. Operator
2. parameter
3. value

Each simple **Expression** mentioned can be combined into a compound expression.

```
public SimpleExpresssion createcompound(SimpleExpression simple1,SimpleExpression simple2)    
    {
        CompoundExpression ce = new CompoundExpression();
        ce.lhs(simple1);
        ce.rhs(simple2);
        ce.operator(AND);    
    }
```

A complex example would look like ((1AND2)OR(3OR4))
where 1,2,3,4 are Expression objects.
I am looking for a logic to evaluate the expression based on the parenthesis preference in the expression.
Note:
**CompoundExpression** is a extended class of **Expression** so the final output is a Expression object.
Is it solvable easily? If not what are my options

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Convert the Expression to equivalent postfix expression.
2. Evaluate the postfix expression using a stack.

Answer (score 1):

A complex expression  ((1AND2)OR(3OR4)) can be rewritten to a prefix notation:

```
OR(AND(1,2), OR(3,4))
```

Therefore, the only thing you need is a constructor or a factory method of CompoundExpression with 3 parameters: an operator, left and right abstract expressions:

```
CompoundExpression(Operator o, Expression left, Expression right) {
    this.operator = operator;
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
}
```

Then, assuming that you have 4 simple expressions, building the resulting expression is simple:

```
Expression result = new CompoundExpression(OR, 
    new CompoundExpression(AND, simple1, simple2), 
    new CompoundExpression(OR, simple3, simple4)
);
```

Comment: The solution provided seems to be the way to go. Can it be generalised?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you want to achieve. With such classes you can build manually an Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) of any expression.

Comment: I wanted to evaluate the expression. I did the solution of first converting it to postfix expression and evaluated it using a stack